# Login page loads fast in regular browser, never in via RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to log into a website to scrape my personal data from it. however, every time I try the site seems to load infinitely. When I start Firefox manually (not with R) the site loads very quickly. Why is this different?

Reproducible example:

```r
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://app.truecoach.co/login")

remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this in a clean R Session and the login screen shows up:

```
webpage <- 'https://app.truecoach.co/login'
driver <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = 'firefox', port = 4818L)
remDr <- driver[['client']]
remDr$navigate(webpage)
```